# Makefile. Target_specific variables. Inheritance?

Tags: c, variables, makefile

I am learning how to write good Makefiles. I have to write several gcc compliation commands that would produce different files compiled with different options. I have read about .SECONDEXPANSION but it does not quite satisfy me as it look really ugly and I am not sure how to use it in this case. I would be happy if I got something like this:

```
matrix_o0: opt_flag = -O0
matrix_o1: opt_flag = -O1
matrix_os: opt_flag = -Os
matrix: source = matrix.c
all:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(source) $(opt_flag) -o $@
```

And the result I would like to have is only THREE files (matrix_o0, matrix_o1, matrix_os). Is there any solution? Some kind of polymorphism maybe? :D

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare targets with a recipe, not just target variables.  Like this:

```
source = matrix.c

matrix_o0: opt_flag = -O0
matrix_o1: opt_flag = -O1
matrix_os: opt_flag = -Os

matrix_o0 matrix_o1 matrix_os:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(source) $(opt_flag) -o $@
```

Comment: Yes! It works... almost. I had to put another line:
    all: matrix_o0 matrix_o1 matrix_os
Then it created me 3 files instead of 1.
Thanks! :D